# How to implement such a callcenter function in PHP?

Tags: php, call

It should be something like this:

```
function callcenter($func,$value,$position)
{

}
```

Where $func is the function to be called,

$value is the parameter for $func,

and $position stands for index of $value,

for example,

`callcenter('func',1,2)` should actually call func(null,1)

`callcenter('func',1,3)` should actually call func(null,null,1).

Say,leaving other positions as null.

Comment: It sounds like a refactor may be in order. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

```
<?php
function callcenter($func, $value, $position)
{
    $args = array_fill(0, $position-1, null);
    $args[] = $value;
    
    call_user_func_array($func, $args);
}

function example()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    
    var_dump($args);
}

callcenter('example',1,2);

callcenter('example',1,3);
?>
```

Comment: As I thought, there is a better way than my switch statement.  I'll file this one for future reference. +1

Answer (score 0):

In php it is posible to call a function whose name is stored in a varable, so

```
function callcenter($func,$value,$position)
{
 switch ($position)
  {
   case 1: $func($value); break;
   case 2: $func(null, $value); break;
   case 3: $func(null, null, $value); break;
  }
}
```

There might be a better way to handle the variable number of parameters, but that should get the basic idea across.

Comment: What if $position is 100000?The switch will be extremely long,lol~

Comment: Yep, see my comment to Matthew